# VBA Split Function not allow Null

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am a noob and need help on how I can change code to allow null since there will be null values. I pulled this code from another post and tweaked it to fit my purpose. I am creating a table and split codes from one table, part, and break them out into created table,SplitCodes_Part. It keeps displaying error invalid use of null at codelist = split(!code,",") part of the script. The code field in the part table may have multiple codes that are separated with a comma and no space.  I want to break those out into individual rows.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Code below:

```
Sub split()


    Dim dbb As DAO.Database
    Dim tdff As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fldd As Field
    Set dbb = CurrentDb()
    Set tdff = db.CreateTableDef("SplitCodes_Part")
    Set flddA = tdff.CreateField("ID", dbText, 250)
    Set flddB = tdff.CreateField("Bookid", dbText, 250)
    Set flddC = tdff.CreateField("Imagefile", dbText, 250)
    Set flddD = tdff.CreateField("Code", dbText, 250)
    Set flddE = tdff.CreateField("ext_Remark", dbText, 250)
    flddE.AllowZeroLength = True
    tdff.Fields.Append flddA
    tdff.Fields.Append flddB
    tdff.Fields.Append flddC
    tdff.Fields.Append flddD
    tdff.Fields.Append flddE
    tdff.Fields.Refresh
    dbb.TableDefs.Append tdff
    dbb.TableDefs.Refresh

    Dim rss As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rss_out As DAO.Recordset
    Dim x As Long
    Dim SplitCodes() As Variant

    Set rss = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT id, bookid, imagefile, code, ext_remark from part")
    Set rss_out = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SplitCodes_Part")
    With rss
        Do
            CodeList = Split(!Code, ",")
            For x = LBound(CodeList) To UBound(CodeList)
                rss_out.AddNew
                rss_out!Code = CodeList(x)
                rss_out!imagefile = rss!imagefile
                rss_out!bookid = rss!bookid
                rss_out!id = rss!id
                rss_out!EXT_REMARK = rss!EXT_REMARK
                rss_out.Update
                rss_out.AddNew

            Next x
            .MoveNext
        Loop Until .EOF
    End With
    rss_out.Close
    Set rs_out = Nothing
    rss.Close
    Set rss = Nothing
    dbb.TableDefs.Refresh



End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if !Code is null? From the question if there is a single value, a single row is output, if there are multiple values in !Code, one row for each value. So what happens if there are no values in !Code, one row, no rows, something else?

Comment: `CodeList = Split(!Code & "", ",")` if you just want it not to error when there's no content...

Comment: CodeList is not a declared variable, SplitCodes is. Do you have Option Explicit in module header?

Comment: You could use the `NZ` function to avoid nulls.

Comment: I would like it to skip record and move to the next if it is null. I will try the suggestions once I get to work. Thank you all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the records having a *Null* Code:

```
Set rss = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select ID, Bookid, Imagefile, Code, ext_remark From part Where Code Is Not Null")
```

Comment: I add null to the select query and code & "" but im getting a new error of  "NO CURRENT RECORD" and there is a record in the table.

Comment: Use: Do Until .EOF

Comment: To be specific it highlights codelist = Split(!Code & "", ",") and states error.

Comment: it has  LOOP UNTIL .EOF..should I put it some where else?

Comment: figured it out. had to create an if statement that if there are no codes then skip it.